# How do I put all entries in upper case using Hibernate

Tags: hibernate, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

How do you put all the letters of a string in the uppercase while persists in the database!

Comment: `string = string.toUpperCase()`?

Comment: I say using hibernate. Is there any configuration I put in that makes all the strings are uppercase?

Comment: No. If a field of an entity is supposed to be in uppercase, then make sure it's in uppercase. For example by writing a setter for this property that transforms its argument to uppercase before saving it in the field, or that throws an exception if its argument is not in uppercase. You really don't want to have a lowercase value in your entity and an uppercase value in the corresponding column of the database. Make them consistent.

Comment: Putting the uppercase on the set would work? `setName(name){name.toUpperCase();}` PS. I reduced the code

Comment: If coded correctly, yes, of course: `public void setName(String name) { this.name = name.toUpperCase(); }`. Why wouldn't it work?

Comment: Nothing wrong. I use it that way, but it has a high cost. I have 56 properties to do that! Thank you very much ;)

Comment: If 56 lines of code is a high cost, then you're probably not working on a big application. But why do you store values in uppercase in the first place? You can always **display** any value in uppercase. If you **store** them in uppercase, then there's no way you can get back the original value. And SHOUTING is ugly.

Comment: Put everything in capital letter motivated to standardize input. Prevent users from putting: Jhon Smith and another jhon petter. Yes it is. And SHOUTING is ugly. Lol... I have to think if this is the best way out!